# Excel Multi condition Loop

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am trying to set up a sheet to track shipping information in my company. the shipping record contains a column for date, customer, part number, and quantity. I am trying to set up my tracker to automatically arrange the data across a sheet with the dates across each column like a calendar, and each row as a different part based on part number and customer.

basically, i'm trying to set up an if statement that looks at the date at the top of my chart (Example A1) and check the entire column of dates on the shipping sheet, and then check for the correct part number, and then check for the correct customer, and then add in all of the quantity of shipments for that order so i can easily see everything for that specific date without having to search the entire sheet and check all of the dates individually.

the if statement i tried was

=IF(D1='Sheet2'!A:A,IF('Sheet2'!B:B="customerName",IF('Sheet2'!C:C="partNumber",'Sheet2'!D:D,0),0),0)

d1 is the cell for the date in my chart, column A in Sheet2 is the date, B is the customer name, C is part number, and D is quantity.

it always returns a value of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b):

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet2'!D:D,'Sheet2'!A:A,D1,'Sheet2'!B:B,"customerName",'Sheet2'!C:C,"partNumber")
```